# x86 Assembler does putchar need an address in the stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, putchar

My task is, to put a local variable onto the lowest address on the stack. I have only 1 local variable and that's my int counter.

In the following code you can see that my compiler made a 32 byte stack and put the local variable on the address 28(%esp):

```
_main:
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
andl    $-16, %esp
subl    $32, %esp
call    ___main

movl    $0, 28(%esp)  #int counter = 0;
```

My question now is: Can I put my variable on the address 0(%esp) because somewhere in the code some registers are put onto this address to print them afterthat out as you can see here for example:

```
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    _putchar
```

Is now the lowest address 0(%esp) or 4(%esp) ? 
I'm confused because both of these addresses work when I compile this program.

Here is the second function void add(int z, char* string):

```
_add:
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
subl    $24, %esp
...
...
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    _putchar
```

There are no local variables in this function. Only the 2 Parameters int z and char* string.

So how many bytes do I need at least?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, 32 bit calling convention uses stack to pass arguments. No, you should not overlay your locals with outgoing arguments as those are owned by the callee and may be destroyed.

Comment: okay thank you, one more question: 
If I have 2 function(main, void add(int number, char *string)) and no local variables in the add() function.
How big should i make the stack ? The stack has to be as small as possible. I have putchars in the function

Comment: If the stack needs to be 16-byte aligned, you need to subtract 12 from esp before calling putchar. If alignment is not required, you only need space for the parameters of the function(s) you call (i.e., 4 bytes). In 32-bit mode, the stack never used to need alignment, but recently that has changed. Since the main function you’ve shown aligns the stack, it’s safe to assume it is required.

Comment: Does that mean, if i have 2 parameters, I need 2x4bytes for them ? Do I need another byte for putchar ?